# jQuery unexpected token, where?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I can't get this short hello-world-like ajax function work for hours.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` is all the error message.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').click(function(){
        $.ajax(function(){
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'admin_ajax.php',
            data: {change_rights:8},
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The unexpected token will be in the response to the AJAX request. jQuery is trying to parse it to an object and failing because the response is not valid JSON.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's not true. There's nothing to suggest the response should be json, and nothing in the code that is attempting to parse json. $.ajax doesn't require a function(){}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `function()` from Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
//-----^-
    type:   'POST',
    url:    'admin_ajax.php',
    data:   {change_rights:8},
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

[**Documentation : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: That's the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
        type:   'POST',
        url:    'admin_ajax.php',
        data:   {change_rights:8},
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
    });
});
```